# Cannot deploy Mapbox GL Native on Lambda using Serverless

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, serverless, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to deploy from Linux a simple Mapbox GL Native app on AWS Lambda using Serverless. My original intention was to have a map image sent to the client as a data url. I initially tried to use the "Rendering a map tile" example from the url below as a starting point:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/tree/master/platform/node

I found that including mapbox-gl-native results in an internal server error simply by requiring it even without additional code that references the library:

```
var path = require('path');
var mbgl = require('@mapbox/mapbox-gl-native');
var sharp = require('sharp');

var serverless = require("serverless-http");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
})

module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

My serverless.yml file is as follows:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

functions:
  app:
    handler: app.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
```

In the example above if you remove the mapbox-gl-native requirement you will get the 'hello world' response. Is it possible to deploy mapbox-gl-native on Lambda with Serverless?